# Why can I get only 25 YouTube video from a feed?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api

I have this code on C#/.NET :

```
string user = "Username";
string feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + user + "/uploads";
Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
{
    // print video
}
```

but I can retrieve only 25 video!

I [know](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html) the max number of video in a feed is 999 :

> The API returns a videos feed in response to a request to search for videos. A videos feed contains a maximum of 999 entries. To retrieve search results, send an API request to the following URL:
>
> `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/projection/videos?v=2`

So why 25?

Tried with `uploads/?start-index=0&max-results=999` but nothing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 999 figure refers to the maximum number of videos that can exist in a playlist or feed:

> The API returns a videos feed in response to a request to search for videos. A videos feed contains a maximum of 999 entries.

By default it returns 25 results, though you can override this:

> The max-results parameter specifies the maximum number of results that
>   should be included in the result set. This parameter works in
>   conjunction with the start-index parameter to determine which results
>   to return. For example, to request the second set of 10 results – i.e.
>   results 11-20 – set the max-results parameter to 10 and the
>   start-index parameter to 11. The default value of this parameter is
>   25, and the maximum value is 50. However, for displaying lists of
>   videos, we recommend that you set the max-results parameter to 10.

http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#max-resultssp

The maximum value of `max-results` is 50, so you'll need to issue multiple requests using `start-index` to fetch each block of results.