# Youtube's 25 videos-limit

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

When I search YouTube for videos with something like:

```
var SearchUri = string.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={0}", searchText);
```

the response contains entries for 25 videos.

How can I retrieve the entries for remaining videos?

Comment: I think this question has already been asked here: [why-can-i-get-only-25-youtube-video-from-a-feed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355848/why-can-i-get-only-25-youtube-video-from-a-feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if there's a problem in v2 API.

Use V3 of youtube API

try this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=steve&part=id&key=YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY&max-results=50
```

Refer this [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Searching_for_Videos)

Answer (score 0):

From [YouTube API v2.0 – API Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters)

> max-results
>
> The max-results parameter specifies the maximum number of results that
>   should be included in the result set. This parameter works in
>   conjunction with the start-index parameter to determine which results
>   to return. For example, to request the second set of 10 results – i.e.
>   results 11-20 – set the max-results parameter to 10 and the
>   start-index parameter to 11. **The default value of this parameter is
>   25, and the maximum value is 50.** However, for displaying lists of
>   videos, we recommend that you set the max-results parameter to 10.